# Will dual pivot caliper brakes work on cantilever fork?

Tags: mountain-bike, fork, rim-brake

I have 26” tokyobike(used to be 650c) with tektro r369 which are long reach dual pivot caliper brakes. I want to change the fork so I can put wider tyres. Will the 26” mtb cantilever fork work with the brakes? Will the brake pads reach the rim?
I’ve post the pic of the fork I mentioned from ebay.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need fork with approximately the same axle to crown length (i.e. the fork legs are the same length as your current fork), with a proper brake mounting hole at the top of the forks. The hole in the forks in the picture is for mounting mudguards or fenders and is not suitable for mounting a caliper brake.

Comment: What makes you think that this hole is not suitable for mounting a caliper brake? In my opinion if the long-reach caliper brake is not interfering with the brake bosses and with the new tyre, the setup will work.

Comment: @Mike because the fork is designed for cantilever or linear pull brakes.

Comment: A hammer made for putting nails can pretty decently serve in cracking nuts (if nothing better is at hand), this still my question remains unanswered. I'd say the other way round, a fork made for caliper brakes is most likely not suitable for cantilever brakes (even if one brazes the brake bosses on) due to lack of sideways strength.